# How to create a sequence of dates in MariaDB without using a temporary variable?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Reference for database schema: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House

The request for a sequence of dates started from the problem of presenting this: Who is in a particular room during the **full** week beginning at some date? The request is to list all including those days when the room is empty.
In other words the output should look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+
| i          | last_name |
+------------+-----------+
| 2016-11-21 | McDonnell |
| 2016-11-22 | McDonnell |
| 2016-11-23 | Whitford  |
| 2016-11-24 | Whitford  |
| 2016-11-25 | NULL      |
| 2016-11-26 | NULL      |
| 2016-11-27 | Berry     |
+------------+-----------+
```

The attempt to solve it resulted in excessive usage of two temporary variables! See sql script below.

```
SELECT @row := '2016-11-20' as var1;
SELECT @row2 := '2016-11-20' as var2;

select t1.cur_date as i, t2.last_name
from
(select @row2 := ADDDATE(@row2, 1) as cur_date from booking LIMIT 7) as t1
LEFT JOIN (
select cur_date, gg.last_name
from booking as bb CROSS JOIN
(select @row := ADDDATE(@row, 1) as cur_date from booking LIMIT 7) as dd
INNER JOIN guest as gg ON bb.guest_id = gg.id
where bb.room_no = 207
and ADDDATE(bb.booking_date, bb.nights) >= ADDDATE(cur_date, 1)
and bb.booking_date <= cur_date
) as t2 USING (cur_date)
```

Any ideas on how to simplify this or in general how to execute an sql query across a set of dates without doing the perhaps hackerish approach with the temporary variables?

Comment: A calendar table will make this and many other situations much easier to handle.

Comment: Link for the calendar table?

Comment: @DanBracuk do you need to create such a table or is it given inherently by the system (mariadb database here) ?

Comment: See "seq" tables in MariaDB for how to build calendar-like table on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using @row variables to build the sequence, you can simplify using the sequence storage engine (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/), which is installed by default from MariaDB 10.1.

```
SELECT d.date, 
 (
      SELECT b.last_name
      FROM booking AS a
      LEFT JOIN guest AS b
      ON a.guest_id = b.id
      WHERE a.room_no = '207' 
      AND a.booking_date <= d.date 
      AND a.booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY > d.date
 )
 FROM 
 (
      SELECT '2016-11-21' + INTERVAL (seq) DAY AS date
      FROM seq_0_to_7
 ) AS d;
```